# Solving an integral equation (FTC)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-equations

> Find all functions $f(x)$ continuous and non-negative that have the property that the area under the graph is $\frac{1}{3}$ the rectangle with opposite vertices at $(0,0)$ and $(x,f(x))$ and sides parallel to the coordinate axes.

I tried to solve it and I got the following:

$\int_0^x f(x)dx = \frac{1}{3} x f(x) \\ \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{1}{3} \frac{d}{dx} (xf(x))$

but I could not go further. Any idea?

Comment: I think the equation must be $\int_0^xf(t)dt=\frac{1}{3}xf(x)$.

Comment: Then, the conclusion that $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(xf(x))$ is 'almost' correct: the $\frac{1}{3}$ disappeared. It should be $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{dx}(xf(x))$.

Comment: Yeah it was a typo, I meant $1/3(xf(x))'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x):=xf(x)$. Then

$$\frac{g(x)}x=\frac{g'(x)}3$$ is a separable ODE that integrates as

$$3\log x+c=\log g(x)$$

and finally

$$f(x)=\frac{g(x)}x=cx^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation is not correct, it should be
$$\int_0^xf(t)dt=\frac{1}{3}xf(x).$$
Using FTC, then, we have
$$\begin{split}f(x)&=\frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{dx}(xf(x))
\\&=\frac{1}{3}f(x)+\frac{1}{3}xf'(x)\end{split}$$
so $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{2}{x}$$
so $$\ln(f(x))=2\ln(x)+C_1$$
so the general solution is $$f(x)=Cx^2,\,C\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: How can I make sure that $f$ is differentiable?